# Solving for unknown in bit-wise algebra

Tags: python, bitwise-xor

Suppose I have 3 bytes, X Y and Z.

X XOR Y results in Z.

I know what X and Z are, but I don't know what Y is, so I'm writing a quick script to figure this out.

Though, I don't know how I would even begin. I did a couple of them by hand and it was simply a matter of comparing each bit one by one, but how can I do this in python? My procedure for solving for Y doesn't seem clear enough.

Since I just need to actually use something like this, it would be enough to either write it or just use something that does this for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `x ^ y == z`, then `x ^ z == y`. You can verify this in Python with

```
>>> X = range(256)  # all byte values
>>> Y = range(256)
>>> all(x ^ z == y for x in X for y in Y for z in [x^y])
```

Comment: Oh, didn't realize it was that simple!

Comment: That's right.  And it's not magic: it's pretty much the most important property of XOR.